# multiple sparse input keras single output in R

Tags: r, keras, sparse-matrix, multiple-input

I am trying to implement deep learning with sparse data using R with KERAS and tensorflow library. I have a 20 rows by 26 columns of real valued data ranging from 0 up to 1000. the element in each row must sum close 1000. Some of them have been removed because of too small value. Every element is quantity measurement. Each row is like the following.

row 1: 3  1.6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  10  0.19  0  0  0  3  0  0  7  150  828.01  0  0  0  2.2  0

row 2: 7.8  13  0   0   0   0   4   6   0   0   13  0   0.19    0   2   0   3.8 0   0   200 750.21  0   0   0   0   0

Each of this has boiling point measurement (respectively)

-39  -5  100    15  14  72  52  89  47  51  25  54  100 100 100 54  80  54  86  56  54  55  54  100 100 138

For each observation (e.g. row 1), I have an actual boiling point measurement. For example row 1 is 49, row 2 is 40. The objective is to predict each of this observation boiling point based on row 1 and boiling measurement and then compare it with the actual.

So far my attempt is put model in keras_model_sequential `model <- keras_model_sequential()` and use relu as activation function. 
How do I model this using tanh activation function or arctan activation function?

For example tanh(row1 /1000) * boiling_point row_1. 
Any suggestion or alternative approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use R for this task? I would recommend using Python since there is a very extensive Keras documentation for python (and I cant find one for R). That said, [here](https://keras.io/activations/) you can find a description of how to determine the activation function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am very new in deep learning realm. The data set example above is actually already reduced from 369 columns down to 26 column and 170 rows down to 20 rows. Usually there are more columns (variables) than rows.